# Cannot find module 'fs' with Typescript and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs

My coding language is typescript. Therefore, I added `@types/node` to my project.
When I build my project (an angular app), I get the error `Cannot find module 'fs'`.
Curiously, my IDE has no problems with it. It redirects me to the fs sources and makes suggestions.

I import it like that:
`import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';`

Require didn't help either: `const fs = require('fs');`

Do I miss something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: You can not use NodeJS in-built module in your Angular app including `fs` module

Comment: IDE doesn't have problems with it exactly because you installed @types/node

Comment: @ArifKhan: Why is this not possible? I thought @types/nodes is for this case?
Actually, the error comes from `@google-cloud/speech`. So, it is not possible to use Google Cloud Speech in my app?